# Modifiying all data in a column using Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following column in a CSV file (please note some rows may consist of random amount of activities):

```
Activities
[{'id':18, 'name': 'Football'}, {'id': 35, 'name': 'Rugby'}, {'id': 10736, 'name': 'Hockey'}]
[{'id':16, 'name': 'Chess'}, {'id': 98, 'name': 'Fencing'}]
[{'id':35, 'name': 'Rugby'}, {'id': 47, 'name': 'Marathon'}, {'id': 99, 'name': 'Baseball'}]
```

I have imported the CSV into a Pandas DataFrame:

```
 df = pd.read_csv('activites.csv')
```

I want to modify the column so it will be like this:

```
Activities
Football|Rugby|Hockey
Chess|Fencing
Rugby|Marathon|Baseball
```

I appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert values to dictionaries and then extract `Name` with `join` by `|` for output string:

```
import ast

f = lambda x: '|'.join(y['name'] for y in ast.literal_eval(x))
df['Activities'] = df['Activities'].apply(f)
print (df)
                Activities
0    Football|Rugby|Hockey
1            Chess|Fencing
2  Rugby|Marathon|Baseball
```